# MVC: Cannot get redirected to the page when clicking on the emailed url

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, redirect, forms-authentication, returnurl

I could not fine exactly the same issues here, so I decided to ask my question:

I have a logic that generates a link to a page and emails that link to a user:

```
var ticketUrl = "<a href='"
    + @Url.Action("Index", "TicketDetail", new System.Web.Routing.RouteValueDictionary(new { id = newTicketId }), "http", Request.Url.Host)
    + "'>Go to your ticket</a>";

var response = EmailHelper.SendApproveTicketEmail(newTicketId, ticketUrl);
```

After that, the user is supposed to click on the `Go to your ticket` link, hit the login page, get authenticated and be redirected to the page with the url provided.

Now, when user clicks on the link it brings him to the login page, where he has to login and it brings him to the default page in the application.

I believe there supposed to be some way that would redirect user to the specified page right after he logs in.

How can he be redirected to the correct page?

Comment: you may want to go through this link once http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/redirect-to-clicked-page-after-login/

Comment: or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25392386/mvc-4-redirect-user-after-login

Comment: I think with forms authentication, returnUrl is default behaviour. Also you can indicate what requires authentication and what doesn't. For example using attribute `[Authorize]` or `[AllowAnonymous]` before controller action method. But it would be better if you edit your question specifying what MVC version and authentication type you use.

Comment: I use form authentication and MVC Framework 4.5